# How to evaluate a particular value of an index in a list of lists using Python?

Tags: python, list

I got the following list.

```
lst1 = [[77, 17, None, 77, 21], [49, 91, 96, 83, 72], [60, 70, 64, 27, 14], [70, 53, 94, 61, 60], [48, 18, None, 59, 84]]
```

How can I add another list at the end which indicates whether each column has at least one 'None' value? For the above example, the output should look like below.

```
lst2 = [[77, 17, None, 77, 21], [49, 91, 96, 83, 72], [60, 70, 64, 27, 14], [70, 53, 94, 61, 60], [48, 18, None, 59, 84], [True, True, False, True, True]]
```

A new list `[True, True, False, True, True]` is appended at the end based on the values in lst1'

The list `[True, True, False, True, True]` is generated by considering the column values. That is, for example, the first element of the first list (77), the first element of second list (91) so and so forth.

When we consider all the first elements of inner lists we see there is no None value. Hence it's True.

Comment: Outputs second array `[49, 91, 96, 83, 72]`have no `None` why it is `True`?

Comment: Oh, it looks like it's trying to look at stuff against the grain. So because all of first elements of every list were not None, the first result is True. We're given a list of rows, and want to perform column-by-column analysis.

Comment: Yes, the need is to analyze the column and given are rows. That is by considering 17, 91, 70, 53, 18 and not [49, 91,96,83,72]

Answer (score 3):

Question is a bit unclear, but I think you want this, given that you're trying to determine whether there is no `None` across columns not rows:

```
has_no_none = [None not in column for column in zip(*lst1)]
lst2 = lst1 + [has_no_none]
```

`lst` ends up ending with `[True, True, False, True, True]` as expected.

If you do not need `lst1` after this operation, you can do it in-place with `lst1.append(has_no_none)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension.

```
result = [True if None in x else False for x in lst1]
lst1.append(result)
```

Comment: [[77, 17, None, 77, 21], [49, 91, 96, 83, 72], [60, 70, 64, 27, 14], [70, 53, 94, 61, 60], [48, 18, None, 59, 84], [True, False, False, False, True]] Not the expected output. True, false list is generated considereing the column values

Comment: I see, weirdly worded

Answer (score 1):

If the sub-array contains a None returns true, otherwise False.

```
out = [True if None in val else False for val in lst1]
```

Out:

```
[True, False, False, False, True]
```

Though the output you show is different from what you explain.

Answer (score 1):

Initialise your extra row to `True` for each column, then loop over rows in the list, and if any values in that row are `None`, set the value to `False` at the corresponding position in the extra row.  Then you can construct the whole output list from the input list and the extra row.

```
lst1 = [[77, 17, None, 77, 21],
        [49, 91, 96, 83, 72],
        [60, 70, 64, 27, 14], 
        [70, 53, 94, 61, 60], 
        [48, 18, None, 59, 84]]

summary = [True for _ in lst1[0]]

for row in lst1:
    for i, val in enumerate(row):
        if val is None:
            summary[i] = False

lst2 = lst1.copy() + [summary]

print(lst2)
```

Gives (after inserting newlines for readability):

```
[[77, 17, None, 77, 21],
 [49, 91, 96, 83, 72],
 [60, 70, 64, 27, 14],
 [70, 53, 94, 61, 60],
 [48, 18, None, 59, 84],
 [True, True, False, True, True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all function and list comprehension to perform this in one line.
Refer the code below

```
lst1 = [[77, 17, None, 77, 21], [49, 91, 96, 83, 72], [60, 70, 64, 27, 14], [70, 53, 94, 61, 60], [48, 18, None, 59, 84]]

lst1.append( [all(p) for p in lst1] )

print(lst1)
```

Output is

```
[[77, 17, None, 77, 21],
 [49, 91, 96, 83, 72],
 [60, 70, 64, 27, 14],
 [70, 53, 94, 61, 60],
 [48, 18, None, 59, 84],
 [False, True, True, True, False]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking columns, here is a `pandas` version:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst1)
bools = df.notnull().all().to_list()
lst2 = lst1 + [bools]
```